# How to uncheck the select all checkbox in Ext.selection.CheckboxModel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

When running a `getSelectionModel().clearSelections()` on a grid that uses a Ext.selection.CheckboxModel and all rows was selected using the "select all" check box at the top of the select column, the "select all" check box remains checked.

I did a dirty hack to get around this but I wish to know if there is a cleaner way or if this is a bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd try to put a listener on a grid component to track selection changes (not sure if it will help):

```
listeners: {
   selectionchange: function(grid, selected) {
        if(!selected.length) {
            grid.getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
        }
   }
}
```

Btw, have you tried to do `getSelectionModel().deselectAll()`? clearSelections is deprecated in ExtJS 4.1 and it's runned on view not selection model.

Comment: The documentation clearly state that clearSelection is a private function and as you say it has been deprecated in newer version.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
After reading Vyacheslav Voronchuk's answer I did back and verified that the documentation does indeed say that clearSelection is a private function that does not send an event, thereby not notifying that the checkbox should be cleared.

```
.getSelectionModel().deselectAll()
```

is indeed the way to go.

For historical reasons I include my original dirty hack that I did to get around the problem:

```
var el = Ext.get("gridcolumn-1031");
el.removeCls('x-grid-hd-checker-on');
```

gridcolumn-1031 is the id of the div wrapping the checkbox in my app. It is randomly generated so you need to dom inspect your own to do the same dirty hack.

**Disclamer!** Use at your own peril.

I do not condone dirty hacks like this since it is not likely to survive auto generated id change of my grid, but it will get the app approved by my client while we wait for a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

For removing grid header selection:

`.getSelectionModel().deselectAll()`

didn't work for me because my grid is already empty.

This works though (from above hack):

```
var selectionHeadID = Ext.getCmp('ingameGrid').headerCt.getHeaderAtIndex(0).getId();
var el = Ext.get(selectionHeadID);
el.removeCls('x-grid-hd-checker-on');
```

Hope this helps!